# How to run wkhtmltoxsharp?

Tags: c#, wkhtmltopdf

I have added the wkhtmltoxsharp.dll and Common.Logging.dll to the lust of references. I am using the following code to convert a html file to a pdf file.

`WkHtmlToPdfConverter converter = new WkHtmlToPdfConverter();
byte[] strHTML = converter.Convert("C:\\test.html");
File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\test.pdf", strHTML);
converter.Dispose();`

All it does is give me a pdf file with the content "C:\test.html".

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?
Any help is appreciated!

Regards,
SS

Answer (score 1):

You pass the Convert function the actual html. You want something like this:

```
IHtmlToPdfConverter converter = new MultiplexingConverter();
var bytes = converter.Convert("<html><body><p>blah</p></body></html>");
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\test.pdf", bytes);
```